# Factor Analysis

Tags: probability-or-statistics, rlink

How can I do Factor Analysis with *Mathematica*?

This is my best attempt so far:

```
Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[]
matData = {m, r, c, b, age, edu, mhi};

REvaluate["factanal(" matData ",2)"]
```

The elements of `matData` are arrays containing numerical values.

Comment: Would you like to do it without using `RLink`?

Comment: My priority is that it's as simple as is possible, but beyond that I guess I'd have a mild preference for doing it without RLink - I am more comfortable with Mathematica than R!

But I wasn't able to find anything on google or Mathematica's help that directly related.

Comment: There are a few [demonstrations related to factor analysis](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=factor%20analysis); have you already taken a look at their code for inspiration?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Analysis of Variance Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/guide/AnalysisOfVariancePackage.html) that comes with Mathematica? In particular the [ANOVA](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/ANOVA.html) function.

Answer (score 3):

```
RSet["matR", matData];
REvaluate["factanal(matR,2)"]
```